# BLOB , Insert SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, blob

I have an error that I can't fix ... I really don't know why .

I'm using this code tu upload a file in my database, i want to use the BLOB now .

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    try
                    {

                        //FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\ClientPortalCs\\"
                        //+ GetTheCurrentDirectory(MyTreeView.SelectedNode)
                        //+ "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
                        //LabelFile.Text = "File name: " +
                        //FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                        //FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                        //"Content type: " + FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

                        dbConnection.Open();
                        dynamic queryString = ("INSERT INTO Files (Name,Path,UserUpload,Date,Data) VALUES ('"
                        + FileUpload1.FileName + "','" + GetTheCurrentDirectory(MyTreeView.SelectedNode) + "','" + Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["UserName"] + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + FileUpload1.FileBytes + "' );"
                        + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)");

                        SqlCommand theCommand1 = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConnection);

                        int newFid = (Int32)theCommand1.ExecuteScalar();

                        dynamic queryStringFolder = ("INSERT INTO FILES_FOLDERS (Folder_Id,File_Id) VALUES ('"
                        + MyTreeView.SelectedValue + "'," + "'" + newFid + "')");
                        theCommand1 = new SqlCommand(queryStringFolder, dbConnection);

                        theCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        dbConnection.Close();

                    }
```

In my database the field DATA in the table files is a varbinary(max) .
The parameter for DATA field in the query is the bytes of the file I try to upload .

The error occured is :
"Error Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. "

Can someone tell me why ?

Thank you very much .

Comment: Code like this is just begging for a [SQL Injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/). Please use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that you are passing in the byte []  of your image as a string because you are enclosing it in single quotes.

Remove the single quotes around here:

```
'" + FileUpload1.FileBytes + "'"
```

One more recommendation: Use parameters for your queries. You'll save yourself from sql injection attacks, your queries may run faster and you'll eliminate this kind of mistakes in the future.

**UPDATE** - using parameters:

```
string queryString = "INSERT INTO Files (Name,Path,UserUpload,Date,Data) VALUES (@Name,@Path,@UserUpload,@Date,@Data)";
SqlCommand theCommand1 = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConnection);
theCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",FileUpload1.FileName);
theCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path",GetTheCurrentDirectory(MyTreeView.SelectedNode));
theCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserUpload",Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["UserName"]);
theCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data",FileUpload1.FileBytes);
theCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",DateTime.Now);

int newFid = (Int32)theCommand1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Ok done ! But why did I get this error now ?

Error An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name. Incorrect syntax near ''.

Comment: @Emged you have an incorrect syntax now. Print the sql statement that you are sending to SQL Server and see how it looks.

Comment: Yes ..
INSERT INTO Files (Name,Path,UserUpload,Date,Data) VALUES ('WSB BOXE 20.jpg','Projects//TEST/','Admin','10/28/2011 12:41:16 PM', System.Byte[] );SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)


It doesn't look good ..

Comment: I should be able yo see numbers instead of System.Byte[] , right ?

Comment: @Emged I see... You pass the byte array in inline sql like this. Use parameters instead. Will provide an example in 5 secs.

Comment: I really can't see what is going to change if I use Parameters instead .

Comment: @Emged I've got to go out now but read up parametriezed sql queries.

Comment: @Emged And change all the other pages to parameterized queries as well.

Comment: @Emged, that's the error you get now. But the technique you currently use to create your SQL is not secure. It will be very (extremely) easy for even the most stupid hacker to hack your site if you continue accessing your data this way. And I'm not only talking about the blobs. You even insert a cookie into your SQL without encoding. What if a hacker changes the username cookie into: `Robert',null,null); drop table files; --`?

Comment: Ok I will change all mu functions . 

It is working fine , but I'm thinking about something . 

Why in the database the datafield of a file is <Binary File> ? 

Am I not suppose to see numbers in this field ?